# Django Graphql Auth mutations failing with error unexpected keyword argument 'refresh_token'

Tags: django, graphql

In my project I am using below libraries for django graphql authentication,

django-graphql-jwt
django-graphql-auth
PyJWT

I am running below mutation and some other similar mutations.

```
mutation Register {
    register(
        email: "appleorange@gmail.com"
        password1: "Abcd@2023"
        password2: "Abcd@2023"
    ) {
        success
        errors
        refreshToken
        token
    }
}
```

From yesterday suddenly all mutations started failing with error,

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Register.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'refresh_token'",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 47,
                    "column": 5
                }
            ],
            "path": [
                "register"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "data": {
        "register": null
    }
}
```

I tried changing the library versions for above package by switching to the old one but that did not help.
I don't understand what exactly changed.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using firebase-admin package which is also using pyjwt library similar to django-graphql-jwt.

The django-graphql-jwt library is depend upon older version of pyjwt wherewas firebase-admin depend on >=2.0.0 version.

Since django-graphql-jwt was not getting intended version, it was failing with above mentioned error.